# aws - how to get lambda - node - to use query parameters as event attributes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My lambda works alone ok with a test event of `{"zipcode": "02149"}`

The output is

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "Hello from Lambda to zip code 02149"
}
```

The lambda is called Zipinfo

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Hello from Lambda to zip code '+ event.zipcode
    };
    return response;
};
```

How do I get the lambda to use a query parameter of 'zipcode' and then be able to show that in the output?  I added mapping templates to the integration request and response but could not get them to show the value, what am i missing?  Is it referred to as event? are the mappings correct? Is the URL query string needed / correct?

### Integration Request

[image]

### Integration Response

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is that query string parameters will be under their own key.
So you should be accessing it as `event.queryStringParameters.zipcode`.
You can see an Example Amazon API Gateway Message Event here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html

Answer (score 0):

In your source code I see you implement as below format

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Hello from Lambda to zip code '+ event.zipcode
    };
    return response;
};
```

I think you have already mark **Use Lambda Proxy integration** in **Integration Request** in your API Gateway
If it is true, you will have 2 ways (I think so) to get **Query string data** from API Gateway:

For request `GET /zip/info?zipcode=101`. Input Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration will be like: ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html))

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {String containing incoming request headers}
    "multiValueHeaders": {List of strings containing incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {List of query string parameters}
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

Your `zipcode` will be store in `queryStringParameters`,
then the first option is:

- Mapping template:

```
"zipCodeFromHttpRequest": "$input.params().querystring.get('zipCode')"
```

If you need keep 2 ways to execute the lambda function (directly with you input and API gateway integration) , you have to check the `event` object in your source code to detect where you can get the zip code (`zipcode` or `zipCodeFromHttpRequest`).

- Event object of `Proxy Integration` :
  You can get `queryStringParameters` object from your source code, like

```
const zipcode = event.zipcode || event['queryStringParameters']['zipcode'];
```